# Calculated field with delayed evaluation in a `ReferenceClass`

Tags: r, reference-class

In a stripped-down example, I have an object of `Portfolio` reference class holding individual asset values within the `holdings` field. There is additional field `value`, which is calculated by simply summing the individual values of `holdings`:

```
Portfolio <- setRefClass("Portfolio", 
                         fields = list(holdings = "numeric", 
                                       value = function(v) {
                                           sum(holdings)
                                       })
)
```

Immediately after populating `holdings` slot, it is evident that the `value` slot gets calculated.

```
Portfolio$new(holdings =c(1055.43, 345.7))

Reference class object of class "Portfolio"
Field "holdings":
[1] 1055.43  345.70
Field "value":
[1] 1401.13
```

***Question***: How to rewrite the definition in order to achieve delayed, on-demand evaluation of `value` field, only when it's being called directly with `Portfolio$value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evident that the `value` is evaluated until it is referenced. See

[Auto update of a field (data member) in R reference class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587410/auto-update-of-a-field-data-member-in-r-reference-class)

By default, calling the object has to reference all its fields, thus they are also evaluated.

Comment: You are very welcome! Actually, I would have not asked that question linked above if I saw your post first! Because the code in your "question" is almost the "answer" for that question! So I voted you up :)

Comment: haha, nice synergies there :) let's keep up exploring the big picture via tiny examples interspersed here and there!